# Base encode without special characters (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Base encode like below

> enc   = Base64.encode64('mystring')
>
> Output : "U2VuZCByZWluZm9yY2VtZW50cw==\n"

But when i use this output to set some div ids in the html page,
actual encryption is not shown. As you can see in the above sample, `'\n'` turns out to be a line break when using in html page. And the id of the div now becomes `id="U2VuZCByZWluZm9yY2VtZW50cw=="`
but expected is `U2VuZCByZWluZm9yY2VtZW50cw==\n`

is there any solution for this or any alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
Base64.urlsafe_encode64
```

It removes the new line and uses - instead of + and _ instead of /

You do of course then have to use `Base64.urlsafe_decode64` to decode it.